# Slovakia has been the first state to have not affirmed joining NATO of Sweden and Finland with magnitudinal majority — why?

Tags: nato, sweden, finland, slovakia

There is still a chance (a substantial probability) that [Turkey](https://www.al-monitor.com/originals/2022/09/turkey-renews-veto-threat-sweden-finland-nato-bids) or Hungary would not even affirm it by supermajority or [*any* majority](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2022-07-05/turkey-threatens-to-veto-sweden-and-finland-s-nato-bids) at all given their pro-Russia stances, but so far, [all other legislative bodies of NATO member states supported their joining by at least a 10-fold majority.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweden%E2%80%93NATO_relations)<sup>1</sup> And Slovakia showed the 4<sup>th</sup> highest rejection rate too in absolute terms as well; however, the countries that had an absolute rejection count higher than Slovakia typically had a legislative body at least twice the size that of Bratislava.

So, the question is what political reasons supported the decision of the nay sayers.

**Endnotes**

<sup>1</sup> The French legislation voted in the National Assembly for (209), against (46), absentee (53), and the Senate for, (323) against, (17), and (8), a combined 656 electors present and less than 63 voting against the proposal, less than 10<sup>th</sup> of all present even if the supporters did not reach a ten-fold majority.

Comment: This prose is very dense and really needs to be unpacked. I would suggest starting at the beginning (Sweden and Finland are applying for NATO membership), discussing the process required for this to happen, discussing what other countries have done, and then explaining the issue of Slovakia, Hungary, and Turkey, ideally with a citation to your source for your assertions.

Comment: It would be useful if the question provided details of the vote in Slovakia.

Comment: I would like to point out that Turkey is not pro-Russian and following a balance policy. This policy has gained the trust of both Ukrainians and Russians. You can read the details of the grain deal, POW exchange etc.

Comment: Could you add references to the question (like links to the news reports or official government/parliament announcements)?

Comment: AFAIK NATO membership for Finland and Sweden [got approved by Slovak parliament](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/slovak-parliament-approves-nato-membership-finland-sweden-2022-09-27/)

Comment: @TadeuszKopec that’s not question though, nor was anything implied to the contrary.

Comment: From your wiki source, the lower chamber in France wasn't that "magnitudinal": 209 for, 46 against, 53 abstained. The Senate is not directly elected in France, so somewhat less relevant. (There are no RN seats in the Senate for example, but they have 89 deputies!)

Comment: @Fizz I think the end note is pretty clear: Those against were magnitudinally fewer than those entitled to vote. The example of France is clearly the least supportive after Slovakia (which may appear as a surprise), but Slovakia is qualitatively worse.

Comment: In France it was the LFI which voted against, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 20):

There are various unclear parts in your Q, but if it is why Slovakia's parliament (probably) voted less enthusiastically on the latest NATO expansion is that [the population is](https://www.euractiv.com/section/politics/short_news/most-slovaks-want-russia-to-win-ukraine-war/) nearly as pro-Russia as Hungary is (nowadays).

> Most Slovaks want Russia to win Ukraine war
>
> The representative survey named “How are you Slovakia?” has been conducted by MNFORCE and Seesame agencies and the Slovak Academy of Sciences. Those surveyed had to respond to the survey using a 10-point scale, according to which 1 means a clear victory for Russia and 10 for Ukraine.
>
> Approximately a fifth of respondents said they wish for a clear victory for Russia, with more than half saying they are inclined toward a Russian win. Meanwhile, only a third said they tended towards Ukraine, and only 18% expressed no preference.
>
> **Divisions are clearly noticeable on the party level. For example, the overwhelming majority of voters of the SMER-SD of former Prime Minister Robert Fico are on the Russian side.** [...]
>
> Regarding the geographical differences, only the population of Bratislava has a majority of people wishing for Ukraine to win. [...]
>
> In February 2022, before the invasion, 44% of people blamed NATO and the US for the tension on the Ukrainian borders, while only 33% blamed Russia.
>
> Regarding NATO membership, only 45% supported it in the survey from 2021. Right after the invasion, support has risen, but it has started to decline again recently.

And their own NATO politics [are](https://www.euronews.com/my-europe/2022/03/29/vladimir-putin-used-to-be-popular-in-slovakia-then-he-invaded-ukraine) a bit strange too...

> The Russian invasion of Ukraine also came amid a tortuous debate about Slovakia’s place in NATO.. After years of argument, Bratislava finally signed a Defense Cooperation Agreement (DCA) with the United States in early February.
>
> For its critics, it spells the end of Slovakian sovereignty. Robert Fico, a former prime minister, called it “treason”, despite himself starting the process when in government.

And a bit like Orban, Fico has condemned the Russian invasion but [is opposed](https://www.freiheit.org/central-europe-and-baltic-states/pro-kremlin-disinformers-slovakia-are-using-western-sanctions) to economic sanctions on Russia.

One Slovakian website [says](https://spectator.sme.sk/c/23019126/slovak-parliament-backs-finland-and-swedens-nato-membership.html) it was mainly the far-right which opposed the NATO expansion in parliament

> As many as 126 MPs of 143 present MPs voted for Finland’s accession to the Alliance. Regarding Sweden, 124 of 144 present MPs supported the country’s decision to join NATO on September 27.
>
> In addition to several MPs from different political parties, far-right MPs voted against the protocols en bloc.

So that would give 17-20 oppose or abstention votes (source isn't too clear on that), so that would not be Fico's party, which is socialist. The DCA with the US, back in Feb, [faced](https://apnews.com/article/russia-ukraine-business-europe-slovakia-bratislava-07dfd58fd47d672db840eb37583d8376) a tighter vote though 79-60. From another [article](https://apnews.com/article/russia-ukraine-europe-russia-slovakia-bratislava-35b125a38e65e5556aee0c655861e151) on those protests, it seem the far-right party which opposed both is [People’s Party Our Slovakia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People%27s_Party_Our_Slovakia), but they only have 7 votes in parliament nowadays. On the other hand they have 2021 splinter group in the [The Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_(Slovakia)), which also seems to have voted against, [according](https://www.euractiv.com/section/politics/short_news/slovak-parliament-overwhelmingly-supports-finnish-swedish-nato-accession/) to Euractiv:

> Only members of the far-right parties People’s Party Our Slovakia and The Republic voted against it.
>
> Interestingly, accession has been supported also by members of the SMER party of former Prime Minister Robert Fico. SMER sees the conflict in Ukraine differently than the official Slovak position.

According to Wikipedia, People's Party Our Slovakia won 17 seats in the 2020 election, but suffered several defections including that 5-seat new party splinter in the aftermath. [Seemingly](https://www.euractiv.com/section/politics/short_news/slovakias-far-right-splits-loses-one-mep-and-five-mps/) that was due mainly to disagreements over the party leader's powers rather than other policy.

Comment: Also of some interest, a Russian diplomatic attaché was apparently caught bribing/paying some disinfo websites in Slovakia https://www.lemonde.fr/en/international/article/2022/03/24/in-slovakia-the-disinformant-was-paid-by-moscow_5979091_4.html

Comment: Note that the current government in Slovakia is undergoing a crisis right now (or has just ceased to function, depending on how you look into it). Also, Fico was fighting for survival (several of his close associates have been arrested on charges of corruption, he himself is accused), a chunk of his party split and deserted him, and he found a refuge in anti-EU, far-right rhetoric (despite himself and his party formerly being pro-EU and social oriented party, though with some fondness for former USSR and Russia) and by association, pro-Russian right now. This all played into the voting.